# Transform the data

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following data structure:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'ABC',
    salesData: [
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-01',
        value: 10
      },
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-02',
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'DEF',
    salesData: [
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-01',
        value: 8
      },
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-02',
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I would like to transform this to:

```
[
  {
    name: 'ABC',
    '2017-09-01': 10,
    '2017-09-02': 2
  },
  {
    name: 'CDE',
    '2017-09-01': 8,
    '2017-09-02': 3
  }
]
```

I'm trying to use Underscore's Chain and Map which I'm getting confused. So far I have the following, not sure how do I write the `convertedSalesData` to transform as per the need:

```
_.map(data, function(item) {
    let name = item.name;
    let salesData = item.salesData;
    let convertedSalesData = ?
})
```

Comment: is it mandatory to use underscoreJS?

Comment: use [] bracket instead of . for using dates as keys.

Comment: @HarshPatel: Not really, I'm fine with the plain javascript too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6 you can use spread syntax `...` to get this result.

```js
const data = [{"name":"ABC","salesData":[{"timestamp":"2017-09-01","value":10},{"timestamp":"2017-09-02","value":2}]},{"name":"DEF","salesData":[{"timestamp":"2017-09-01","value":8},{"timestamp":"2017-09-02","value":3}]}]


var result = data.map(function({name, salesData}) {
  return {name, ...Object.assign({}, ...salesData.map(({timestamp, value}) => ({[timestamp]: value})))}
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Looks perfect and using ES6 to achieve the result is awesome. Thanks for sharing the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'ABC',
    salesData: [{
        timestamp: '2017-09-01',
        value: 10
      },
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-02',
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'DEF',
    salesData: [{
        timestamp: '2017-09-01',
        value: 8
      },
      {
        timestamp: '2017-09-02',
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  }
];

var res = data.map(function(a) {
  var obj = {
    name: a.name
  };
  a.salesData.forEach(function(x) {
    obj[x.timestamp] = x.value;
  })
  return obj;
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Nenad Vracar. I perfer to use 'reduce':

```
data.map(({ name, salesData }) => ({
  name,
  ...salesData.reduce(
    (record, { timestamp, value }) => {
      record[timestamp] = value
      return record
    },
    Object.create(null)
  )
}))
```

Comment: I think we can use `{}` directly instead of `Object.create(null)`. which is same thing

Comment: I suggest using Object.create(null) when you just need a plain object for storing k/v pairs. This `{}` created by such way don't inherit stuff from Object.prototype. When you are getting things loop on the object, you will be happy to not writing 'hasOwnProperty'.